# How to initialize a large array with a single value?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement Atkin's sieve in Rust. This requires initializing an array with `false`. The syntax for this on the internet no longer works.

```
fn main() {
    const limit:usize = 1000000000;
    let mut sieve:[bool; limit] = [false];
}
```

I expect this to create an array of size `limit` filled with `false`, instead

> rustc "expected an array with a fixed size of 1000000000 elements, found one with 1 element".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[false]` is an array with one element, i.e., its type is `[bool; 1]`.

What you want is `[false; limit]` instead of `[false]`:

```
fn main() {
    const limit: usize = 1_000_000_000;
    let mut sieve = [false; limit];
}
```

There is no need for the type annotation `[bool; limit]` here as it can be inferred.